# C Trying to search an array for a specific number

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, search

I've been trying to develop a Console Program that Sorts an Array, and then allows the user to search for a specific value within the Array. For the most part, the Sorting Section works fine (although I would like to simplify it to one for loop but it will have to do for now).

However the searching part gives me the number 6487516 every time, no matter what number I put in. I'm certain it has to do with my function find_number, I just do not know what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NOT_FOUND -1
#define num 9

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ask,how_many;
    int user_array[num];
    int sorted_array[num];
    int i,temp,junction;

    printf("type 10 numbers with spaces in between then press enter \n, type the numbers again then press enter, after this press q and then press  enter      ");

    for (i = 0; i<=num ; ++i)
        scanf("    %d      ",&user_array[i]);
    //printf("type ");
    for (i = 0; i<=num ; ++i)
        scanf("    %d      ",&sorted_array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i<=num ; ++i)
        printf("    A : %d  ",user_array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i<=num ; ++i)
        printf("    B : %d  ",sorted_array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i <= num; ++i)
    {
        for (junction = 0; junction <= num - i; junction++)
        {
            if (sorted_array[junction] > sorted_array[junction+1] )
            {
                temp = sorted_array[junction];
                sorted_array[junction] = sorted_array[junction+1];
                sorted_array[junction +1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf (" Left is the Sorted right is the Original");
    for (i = 0; i<= num; ++i)
        printf(" \n %d,         %d   ",sorted_array[i],user_array[i]);

    printf (" What number do you want to search for?\n");
    fflush (stdin);
    scanf (" %d",&ask);
    printf (" how many numbers? \n");
    fflush (stdin);
    scanf (" %d",&how_many);
    int truth = find_number (sorted_array, ask, how_many);
    printf (" %d",&truth);
    return 0;
}

int find_number( const int target[10], int goal, int n)
{
    int z,found = 0,locate;
    int i = 0;
    while (!found && i < n)
    {
        if (target[i] == goal)
            found = 1;
        else        
            ++i;
    }
    if (found)
        locate = i;
    else
        locate = NOT_FOUND;
    return locate;
}
```

Comment: `for( i = 0; i<=num ; ++i) ` should be `for( i = 0; i<num ; ++i) `. Your array is too short otherwise.

Comment: BTW your question is not bad but not very good either. Look at the formatting of your code: too many empty lines and broken indentation. Hard to read. Fortunately, you've put the bug in the first lines :)

Comment: Aside: your lines like `scanf("      %d        ",&user_array[i]);` are wrong, please remove the spaces, *especially the trailing ones* which can affect subsequent input. The leading ones are simply unnecessary (except perhaps a single one when using `%c` format). `scanf("%d", &user_array[i]);`

Comment: The reason for the strange number is here: `printf(" %d",&truth);` That prints the address of `truth`, not the value of `truth`. Remove the `&` to get the value.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Ok so I made the correction, however I am still getting the number  6487516, Do you think its pointing to a memory location?

Comment: check the comment above. use addresses for `scanf` but values for `printf`. And BTW the editing of your post just multiplied your rep sixfold :)

Comment: and on codereview they say we're harsh with newcomers :) we're harsh with newcomers who don't give a damn and want only the answer without efforts.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! @  user3386109 you where right! this fixed the problem!, I think my Array is still a bit messed up though, But I think I can fix that on my own. To all of you guys who took the time to comment, thank you so much!

Comment: chqrlie did a free codereview for you. You should read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `num` should be defined to `10` for arrays to have 10 elements (!)
- you iterate over the array once too many.  The classic C idiom is `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... }` where `n` is the size of the array, ie the number of elements.  Since arrays are `0` based, the last valid index in an array is `n - 1`.
- You have extra spaces in your `scanf()` formats, possibly for cosmetic purposes. Trailing have side effects: `scanf()` will keep read input until it gets something that is not whitespace. Don't do this.
- `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior.  Remove it.
- The `find` function works for any size array, remove the hard coded `10` size in the prototype which is ignored by the compiler anyway.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NOT_FOUND  (-1)
#define NUM 10

int find_number(const int *target, int goal, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ask, how_many;
    int user_array[NUM];
    int sorted_array[NUM];
    int i, temp, junction;

    printf("type %d numbers with spaces in between then press enter\n"
           "type the numbers again then press enter, "
           "after this press q and then press  enter", NUM);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
        scanf("%d", &user_array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
        scanf("%d", &sorted_array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
        printf("    A : %d\n", user_array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
        printf("    B : %d\n", sorted_array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
        for (junction = 0; junction < NUM - i - 1; junction++) {
            if (sorted_array[junction] > sorted_array[junction + 1]) {
                temp = sorted_array[junction];
                sorted_array[junction] = sorted_array[junction + 1];
                sorted_array[junction + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf (" Left is the Sorted right is the Original\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
        printf("%5d, %5d\n", sorted_array[i], user_array[i]);

    printf(" What number do you want to search for?\n");
    scanf("%d", &ask);
    printf(" how many numbers?\n");
    scanf("%d", &how_many);
    int truth = find_number(sorted_array, ask, how_many);
    printf(" %d\n", &truth);
    return 0;
}

int find_number(const int *target, int goal, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (target[i] == goal)
            return i;
    }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Notes:

- you should copy the `user_array` into the `sorted_array` instead of asking the user to enter the numbers again.
- you should use a better algorithm for searching in the sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

This is an idiom in C:

```
#define N   20
int array [N];
for (int j=0;  j < N;  ++j)
     //do something with array[j]
```

Note that it is *not*  `j <= N`.  That causes access to an *un*allocated array element, namely `array[N]`.